# Unspecified content height with Automatic Overflow and header/footer always in view and no scroll wheel on the page

Tags: html, css, layout, overflow, positioning

Okay, so I'm having rather annoying problems with what should be simple code, I've searched for duplicates but it appears to be different in a slight way. Here's my basic layout:

***html:***

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

***css:***

```
html,body,#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    position:   relative;
}

#header {
    position:   fixed;
    top:    0px;
    height: 40px;
    width:  100%;
    color:  white;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#content {
    position:   fixed;
    padding-bottom: 50px; /* to match the footer height*/
    top:    40px;
    bottom: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    width:  100%;
    overflow:   auto;
}

#footer {
    position:   fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 49px;
    width:  100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color:   skyblue;
    font-weight:    bold;
}
```

The idea is that the 3 divs inside the wrapper take up 100% of the page - in other words: all them are **always in view**. Header up top, footer on the bottom and content in the middle respectively.

The footer and header can be fixed size (be it pixels or % of page height), the content I want to automatically take up the rest of the page.

The problem is that the page can be of many different resolutions(so content can't be of fixed height, unless I use javasript). Another thing is that the content div can have variable amount of elements, meaning it has to allow the scrolling of the content while keeping both header and footer in view. The main part is: the scroll-wheel **must be** inside the content div, not page-wide.

I almost have what I want with this css, but some of the content can't be scrolled to when they overflows content div (I'm talking vertical overflows - there will be no horizontal ones). I would really appreciate some help, but this is not as easy/simple as it seems, if possible at all as I think you need a fixed height for overflow: auto.

I want a pure css solution, if possible, so don't mention JqueryMobile to me (or ever).

Here's how it looks right now, notice the scroll-wheel problem on the content div:
[image: layout is almost correct, minus the overflow behaviour]

Answer (score 1):

I hate when this happens...I found the solution just after I posted, decided to try one more thing: I've set the #content height to 'auto' and that did it (since once I drew my own attention to the scroll-wheel, it became apparent the problem is with the div height)! Just need to test and make sure that's the case with all/most browsers!

Maybe it will be helpful to someone else though!